# Calculating the normalizing factor in the VonMises-Fisher distribution on $S^p$

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I'm going quickly through the VonMises-Fisher distribution $M$ on $S^p$ and its properties. Its probability density function is:

$$f(x; \kappa,\mu)= c(\kappa)\exp(\kappa x^T\mu)$$

where $\kappa \times \mu \in[0,\infty)\times S^p$ are fixed parameters and $c(\kappa)$ is a normalizing constant so the whole thing will integrate 1$

My question is

> How do you derive the value of $c(\kappa)$?

I've checked Mardia and Jupp's *Directional Statistics (1999)* which seems to be the standard reference, but I'm still bedazzled by its reasoning which goes like:

"To verify that the density integrates to 1, note that the intersection of
$S^p$ with the hyperplane through $t\mu$ and normal $\mu$ is a $(p- 2)$-dimensional sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Since the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order $\nu$ is
$$I_\nu = \frac{(\kappa/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu +\frac12)\Gamma(\frac12)}\int_{-1}^1e^{\kappa t}(1-t^2)^{\nu -\frac12}dt$$
it follows that

> $$\int_{S^{p-1}}\exp(\kappa\mu^Tx)dx = B\left(\frac{p-1}2,\frac12\right)^{-1}\int_{-1}^1e^{\kappa t}(1-t^2)^{\frac{p-3}2}dt$$
>   with $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ the beta function

We can conclude then
$$c(\kappa) = \left(\frac\kappa2\right)^{p/2-1}\frac1{\Gamma(\frac p2)I_{p/2-1}(\kappa)}$$

My question is: How do you get the highlighted equality?